# Reason for update/delete field in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to create a simple app that forces the user to enter a reason for update or delete when they are editing an existing model through a form.  I have created the model and the associated form.  The part of the model that asks for the update summary works fine, but when it appears, it obviously always has the last update that was entered for the model as part of the update view.  Is there some way I can "blank out" the update summary every time?  I am also trying to create a history of each form and I'm still in the early stages of that.  I see that there are several options available, but I'm still exploring those.  I'm a newbie, so any help you can offer is appreciated!

Here is a copy of my current model:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    customer = models.TextField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    update_summary = models.TextField(max_length=264,unique=True,null=True)
```

I have explored possible using Javascript to blank out the form in the update view but can't seem to get that to work.  I have also considered trying to override the form in the form view, but can't seem to get that to work either.  I ultimately want the update view to show the pizza_name every time as well as the customer view, but I want the update_summary to be blank every time.  I intend to store every update summary on a separate history record to be viewed in a history view somewhere but am working to figure out how to best approach this as well.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I was going to suggest what you say in the end. If you intend to store every update summary to keep history, why waste time solving this problem that will become obsolete? I would make `update_summary` a many to many field with a new `Update` model (or have an `Update` model with foreign key for the pizza). If you really want to solve the blanking problem, overriding the form sounds like it would work. What have you tried and why did it fail?

Comment: Paulo, thanks for the feedback.  I will play with the update_summary/foreign key approach a bit more to see if I can get that approach to work.  When I tried to override the update summary in the form as shown below:                                                                           self.fields['update_summary'].label = ''                                                                                           the box still shows the last update on the form.

Comment: Paulo, in the case of the manytomany field or the foreign key, I am trying to present a blank text box every time to the user upon update.  If I go the manytomanyfield or the foreign key route, the user will have to pick from a predefined set of options, correct?

Comment: No, you can have an `update_summary` in the `Update` model and the user will fill that box. How you present it to the user depends on what you are doing. If you are using the admin you can do it with [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Comment: Ok.  I'll play around with the format and see what I can come up with.  As far as overriding the form, how would I go about blanking out a textfield every time so that it is not rendering the old update status?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, I've never done that. It's certainly not the `label` as you tried, and I think `initial` is just for empty forms. Maybe just `self.fields['update_summary'] = ''` would work. One thing that would certainly work but with a lot more effort would be to exclude `update_summary` from the form and manually add and process a field for it.